# How can I call OrderSend inside custom indicator?

Tags: mql4

I've got an indicator that signals an action by sound and alert:

```
PlaySound("news.wav");
Alert(Symbol()," make an action");
```

I wanted to add there the OrderSend function to auto buy-sell and it looks this way:

```
int ticket;        
PlaySound("news.wav");
Alert(Symbol()," make an action"); 
ticket=OrderSend(Symbol(),OP_SELL,1.0,Bid,2,Bid+7*Point,Bid-7*Point,"Sell",0,0, Red);
```

When the time comes, there is the signal, there is the alert but there are no orders.

It is said that Trading functions can be used in experts and scripts in documentation: [Trading Functions](http://docs.mql4.com/trading)
but it has to be done in some way.

How can it be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't trade in an indicator.  There is a quick dirty way to do this.  You can set a GlobalVariable from the indicator and then have a separate EA that constantly monitors the global.  When the global variable is set the EA can make the trade and then reset the variable value.

Use **`GlobalVariableSet()`** in the indicator and **`GlobalVariableGet()`** in the EA.

Comment: i would suggest using the timestamp as the value used to indicate the condition so the EA can verify it's not using old data before trading. eg have 2 variables, one for buy, one for sell, assign timestamp to the relevant one, and EA resets it to 0 when done.

Answer (score 5):

You don't have permission to do trading in custom indicators, read below article.

http://docs.mql4.com/runtime/tradepermission

I think the easy way is to convert your custom indicator into an Expert Adviser. It won't take much time if you have the experience in `MQL4` coding.

Comment: is it possible to use order functions that read order or account information in an indicator? Or all order/trade/account functions not allowed for use in an indicator?